# Moq - Linq expression in repository - Specify expression in setup

Tags: c#, linq, mocking, moq

I have a method on my interface that looks like:

```
T GetSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria);
```

I'm trying to mock the setup something like this (I realise this isn't working):

```
_mockUserRepository = new Mock<IRepository<User>>();
_mockUserRepository.Setup(c => c.GetSingle(x => x.EmailAddress == "a@b.com"))
    .Returns(new User{EmailAddress = "a@b.com"});
```

I realise I'm passing in the wrong parameter to the setup.
After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626016/131809) I can get it working by passing in the Expression, like this:

```
_mockUserRepository.Setup(c => c.GetSingle(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>())
    .Returns(new User{EmailAddress = "a@b.com"});
```

However, this means if I call the `GetSingle` method with any expression, the same result is returned.

Is there a way of specifying in the setup, what Expression to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind a generic set up, it can be simpler like this.

```
_mockUserRepository.Setup(c => c.GetSingle(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>()))
    .Returns(new User { EmailAddress = "a@b.com" });
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The asker specifically stated he wanted to avoid using a generic expression.

Comment: My memory is a bit vague, but the original question was about mocking the method that accept expression. I think Alex updated the question, as he wants to return different result depending on given expression.

Answer (score 14):

I managed to get this to work:

```
Expression<Func<User, bool>> expr = user => user.EmailAddress == "a@b.com";

_mockUserRepository.Setup(c => c.GetSingle(It.Is<Expression<Func<User, bool>>>(criteria => criteria == expr)))
    .Returns(new User { EmailAddress = "a@b.com" });

User result = _mockUserRepository.Object.GetSingle(expr);
```

Comment: took me a while to find that solution, thank you for that